# How to do internationalization in Spring 3 using annotations?

Tags: java, internationalization, annotations, spring-3

Can somebody give me reference/sample code of Spring 3.0 internationalization (annotation based, without XML)?

Comment: did you tried any thing?

Comment: Was Google broken or why didn't you find [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource)? No annotations, only XML.

Comment: I do not have much idea of spring 3.I need only annotations no XML

Comment: just thinking how annotations can be employed for internationalization?